# How to play sound in USB Sound Adapter Speaker

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I've recently found out that the touch feature of official raspberry pi screen freezes when I play MediaElement sound through a speaker plugged in the audio port of the raspberry pi 3. Is the MediaElement code the same for sound played in USB Speaker?

Answer (score 0):

> I've recently found out that the touch feature of official raspberry
>   pi screen freezes when I play MediaElement sound through a speaker
>   plugged in the audio port of the raspberry pi 3.

It is a known issue. You can check [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/26691358-3f48-4d63-84b5-a6244cb4d42a/multitouch-on-raspberry-touchscreen-v11-crash-windows-iot-last-insider-build?forum=WindowsIoT) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/16b92695-c851-435d-849b-9e29742c0570/audio-stuttering-on-rpi?forum=WindowsIoT).

> Is the MediaElement code the same for sound played in USB Speaker?

Yes. You can check this sample: [IoTCoreMediaPlayer](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTCoreMediaPlayer).